$T - \alpha I$ is a positive operator iff $\alpha$ is $\leq$ every eigenvalue of $T.$
Here is the question I am thinking of(I think we are assuming that our vector space $V$ is finite dimensional):
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is self-adjoint and $\alpha \in \mathbb R.$
$(a)$ Prove that $T - \alpha I$ is a positive operator if and only if $\alpha$ is less than or equal to every eigenvalue of $T.$
My attempt:
For $(a).$
For the forward direction, Assume that $T - \alpha I$ is a positive operator then
$$\langle (T - \alpha I) v, v \rangle \geq 0 \implies \langle Tv,v \rangle - \alpha \langle v, v \rangle \geq 0 \implies \langle \lambda v,v \rangle - \alpha \langle v, v \rangle \geq 0 \implies \lambda \geq \alpha $$ for any $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T.$
My question is: Do I need to use that  $T - \alpha I$ is self adjoint in any step in this direction?
Can someone help me please in answering my above question?

How did you turn $Tv$ into $\lambda v$?

For any operator $T$ there is an associated matrix $[T]$ that has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$. Then if $V$ is the matrix whose columns contain eigenvectors and $\Lambda={\rm diag}(\lambda_i)$, $[T]=V\Lambda V^{-1}$ and $[T-\alpha I]=V\Lambda V^{-1}-\alpha VI V^{-1}=V (\Lambda - \alpha I) V^{-1} $. If $\lambda_i>\alpha$ for all $i$ then all diagonals of $\Lambda - \alpha I$ are positive and so $T-\alpha I$ is a positive operator.

Where is the $\alpha$ mentioned in the question used in your solution? @TedBlack

Concerning the first question on selfadjointness, for $\implies$ this assumption is not essential. However for $\Longleftarrow $ it is essential. Indeed let
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix} $$
is positive definite as $\langle Tv,v\rangle =(v_1+v_2)^2$ and the eigenvalues are equal $1.$ However $T-I$ is not positive definite, since $\langle (T-I)v,v\rangle=2v_1v_2.$

which question are you referring to? How did you know that $T - I$ is not positive definite? How do you know that T is positive definite? How did you know that the eigenvalues are 1?

"My question is: Do I need to use that  $T - \alpha I$ is self adjoint in any step in this direction?"  Concerning your other three questions from your comment, try to solve them yourself as the are easy. Do you know that the eigenvalues of upper triangular matrix are the coefficients on the diagonal?

yes I know, sorry about that

Then how should I correct my proof then?

For my previous questions, I think I just should use the matrix of $T$ over say the standard basis and then compute the inner product and see. Am I correct? What only bothers me is why $T - I$ is not positive definite? I applied it to $e_1$ and I got zero which is ok. Should I check if it is self adjoint or not? How can I do that?

Sorry, you have asked about selfadjointness only in one direction. I have extended the answer. Concerning $T-I$ in the example take $v=e_1-e_2.$ The matrix $T$ is not selfadjoint as $0=\langle Te_1,e_2\rangle \neq \langle e_1,Te_2\rangle =2$

Ok thank you. Is my proof of the forward direction correct? I think I will accept your answer and then post a new question about my remaining questions, is that sounds like a good idea?

Thanks for accepting. Your forward direction proof is correct. Concerning the posting of a new question I am not good in advising and in the MathExchg site politics. You should decide yourself. Good luck.

If it were not given that $T$ is normal because it is self-adjoint, then diagonalization might be impossible for $T$, and the direct sum of the eigenspaces might be a proper subspace of $V$. In that case, one could only prove the "only if" part of (a), because not every vector could be expressed as a sum of eigenvectors.
If the space $V$ is finite-dimensional, then one can take $T$ as a matrix. $T$ is normal so it can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix $U$, that is, $T = U^{H}\Lambda U$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of eigenvalues of $T$, then it is easy to check (a) and (b).
If the dimension of the space can be infinite, things can be harder. In infinitely dimensional cases I'm not capable of providing decent answers, but I suggest you search about self-adjoint operators and spectral theorem.

I'm sorry that I found that @Ted Black had already provided this direction of solution before.

so you are saying that my solution is incorrect? Why it is incorrect? The given of the problem are exactly as I stated them
